# Alternative to GetRecordInfoFromGuids - Get IRecordInfo without typelib being registered

Tags: com

GetRecordInfoFromGuids requires the typelib to be registered, but I don't want to register my typelib (project requirements) because I use it with:

```
#import "ComService.tlb"
```

How can I get the IRecordInfo without using GetRecordInfoFromGuids?

Comment: I don't follow, #import is compile time.  It has nothing to do with whether or not there's a registry key that helps locating the .tlb at runtime.

Comment: Right, #import is early binding. The problem is that GetRecordInfoFromGuids will query the registry. 

I would like to get the record info directly from the tlb that I import. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [GetRecordInfoFromTypeInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221422.aspx) function.
The first parameter of this function is a pointer to the ITypeInfo interface.

You can manually load the typelib with the [LoadTypeLibEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221249(v=vs.85).aspx) function and find the required ITypeInfo pointer.

Comment: LoadTypeLib/LoadTypeLibEx require that I embed the typelib as a resource into my COM server executable file (.exe).

I don't want to register the typelib on the system (this is a private interface) nor ship the .tlb with the application.

Comment: LoadTypeLibEx not required typelib registration. You can load typelib from file or resource.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Registration-Free COM.  You can define COM registrations in your binary's manifest files instead of it being in the registry.  I've used UDTs in this scenario and it works great.  See this walkthrough:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx